# Chrome extension cannot access my react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cryptography, apache2

I'm creating a react app with a phantom wallet connection. it's working on my local machine. but I added it to the apache2 server it's not working. Does anyone have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when phantom extension is added in chrome browser it injects window.solana object in browser and from this you access phantom wallet.

But in mobile there is no chrome extension for chrome app.

So use phantom mobile app in-built browser. It will work fine because there is window.solana object in phantom mobile app.